# NDK_ROOT path for ndk r11 in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, python, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to set up Cocos2d-x for Android in Windows using python, but my ROOT values give me an error.

My path to my ndk folder is: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r11

When I try to run setup.py is asks "Please enter the path of NDK_ROOT: ". I enter in my path to the ndk but it then says: "Error: "ndk folder path here" is not a valid path of NDK_ROOT. Ignoring it.

I have also tried manually entering it in my environmental variables, but it still does not work. What is my error here?

My adk folder contains the following:

- build (folder)
- platforms (folder)
- prebuilt (folder)
- python-packages(folder)
- sources (folder)
- toolchains (folder)
- CHANGELOG.md (md file)
- ndk-build (Windows command script)
- source.properties (properties    file)

Edit:

I have now gotten the NDK to accept on the build folder in my previous location, but there is still an issue with the NDK when I try to create a project.

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128567/cocos2dx-android-build-error-arm-linux-androideabi-g-no-such-file-or-direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some changes made on the new NDK r11 release and some tools were moved to different folders, I guess cocos2d-x scripts need to be updated to support the latest NDK release.
You can wait for a new cocos2d-x release or use the previous NDK (r10e) version.

Comment: This ended up being correct. The new version had come out a week before I started the project, and my instructions were from a couple weeks prior with no release number. Found a link to the old r10e version.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set relative path that work on all other fellow system without changing again and again then set ndk root path in such a way.

NDK_ROOT="$APP_ROOT/../your ndk name"

your ndk is placed one directory behind the proj.android file.

Answer (score 0):

I know android studio should set you ndk path in local.properties,there is the setting:

> ndk.dir=C:\android-ndk-r10e 
>   sdk.dir=C:\Studio_SDK

Comment: The error is in Cocos2d-x. When i run setup.py in the cocos folder this is where the issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "\" at the end. I know it sounds silly, but I had the same problem when setting up on my MacOs.

Beyond that, see if you'll encounter other problems like.... wrong toolchain version when compiling

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that at the time of this post, the NDK11 has just been released and the current version of Cocos2dx does not support it. I had to find a download link elsewhere to download an older version.