# Cocos2dx Android build error: "arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, c++, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I downloaded the latest cocos2dx(3.10) and NDK(r11). I have the following error when I executed `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`.

Error:

```
~/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r11/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
```

Then I found in `NDK Revision History` [here](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html) for r11 the following:

`Removed GCC 4.8. All targets now use GCC 4.9.`

Are there workarounds to switch cocos2dx settings to 4.9?

Comment: You can supply your own Application.mk when using cocos2dx can't you? So you should be able to specify the toolchain to use with `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION`.

Answer (score 3):

In your NDK directory create RELEASE.txt file and enter the version, e.g.

r11c (64-bit)

Comment: It helped me to get through current error (The system cannot find the file specified.). But there are another errors yet. Anyway, thank you for good idea.

Comment: I am having the same error. I am using version 10, it even has release.txt file with r10e ( 64 bit) written in it. Can you help me here?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and I solved it by downgrading my NDK to the 10 version. I think Cocos2d-X may not be compatible with the NDK 11, since the RELEASE.txt file is missing from it.

Answer (score 1):

I started with NDK 11 which didn't work. Possible problem as you told is RELEASE.txt doesn't exist for that but then I downgraded to NDK 10e, still didn't work even though RELEASE.txt was present. Then I had to downgrade to NDK 9d which worked without any modifications.