# Error trying to update cocos OpenSSL

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I received a message about OpenSSL security. I did the following http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2016/04/openssl-update/ and now there is an error i don't understand in my project.

15:56:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project app ****
python /Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2/build_native.py -b release all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
"mk start!!!!!!!!!"
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES is jni/../../Classes 
CPP_FILES is jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp jni/../../Classes/BaseLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/Character.cpp jni/../../Classes/DamageInfo.cpp jni/../../Classes/DotchiLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/DotchiScrollView.cpp jni/../../Classes/DotchiSprite.cpp jni/../../Classes/DotchiStatus.cpp jni/../../Classes/Facility.cpp jni/../../Classes/FacilityLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/GameLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/GameStatus.cpp jni/../../Classes/HowToLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/NumberSprite.cpp jni/../../Classes/OpeningLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/SaveUtil.cpp jni/../../Classes/StatusLayer.cpp jni/../../Classes/TapInfo.cpp jni/../../Classes/TroubleLayer.cpp 
Android NDK: jni/../../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'chipmunk' in import path
jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./Android.mk:236: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
  File "/Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2/build_native.py", line 159, in 
make: Entering directory `/Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2'
make: Leaving directory`/Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2'
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
    build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
  File "/Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2/build_native.py", line 146, in build
    do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
  File "/Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2/build_native.py", line 82, in do_build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Applications/cocos2d-x-3.10/projects/app/proj.android_v2 ] fails!

15:57:04 Build Finished (took 9s.912ms)

```
in the android.mk file in the ui folder.


LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,freetype2/prebuilt/android)
$(call import-module,chipmunk)
$(call import-module,platform/android)
```

I have cocos2dx 3.10 and ndk r9d when using r11c I get couldnt find gcc toolchain error

Answer (score 0):

so the problem happens only when you use the NDK 11? I've had a similar problem, in which I couldn't build my project with the NDK 11 and I solved it by downgrading my NDK to the 10 version. I think Cocos2d-X may not be compatible with the NDK 11, since the RELEASE.txt file is missing from it.

Check this thread: [Cocos2dx Android build error: "arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128567/cocos2dx-android-build-error-arm-linux-androideabi-g-no-such-file-or-direct/36579025#36579025)

Comment: Yes, NDK 11 is no good for what you are trying to do. Use 10 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

Add RELEASE.txt to your ndk path and add following

```
r11c (64 bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in Cocos2dxv3.0pre-alpha version.
Follow the below Link:-
http://www.bengigi.com/cocos2d-x-fix-for-openssl-problem/
You just need to download this curl library from here and replace the stuffs there in your existing cocos2dx folder.
For me it works with build the project option but it may create issue with clean build,may be works also for clean-build.Firstly suggest to build it only with updating curl lib.